# kendo angular dropdownlist does not show the default item

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I have a kendo dropdownlist for angular which is below:

```
<kendo-dropdownlist style="padding: 0.25em;" [defaultItem]="'defaultItem'"[data]="turlist" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" textField="turbine_name"
valueField="turID" >
</kendo-dropdownlist>
```

the default value is :

```
public defaultItem: { text: string, value: number } = { text: "Select item...", value: null };
```

but when my dropdownlist binded it does not show "select item..."

Answer (score 2):

Please read the [documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/dropdownlist/default-item/) carefully.

In case you want to use the `kendo-dropdownlist` in your HTML like that:

```
<kendo-dropdownlist
           style="padding: 0.25em;"
           [defaultItem]="defaultItem"
           [data]="turlist"
           [(ngModel)]="selectedValue"
           [textField]="'turbine_name'"
           [valueField]="'turID'" >
</kendo-dropdownlist>
```

please change your `defaultItem` to:

```
public defaultItem: { turbine_name: string, turID: number } = { turbine_name: "Select item...", turID: null };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the single quotes

`[defaultItem]="'defaultItem'"` ==> `[defaultItem]="defaultItem"`

consider accepting the answer if works.
:)